# Heroku REST api Call in java

Tags: java, rest, heroku

can we connect to heroku using webservices or anything else . i want to set up an integration in java which should login in ito heroku and run my application.?

Answer (score 2):

There is an out-dated doc on the [Heroku REST APIs](https://github.com/heroku/heroku/blob/master/REST) that will give you the basic idea.  Unfortunately the most up-to-date reference is the [Heroku command-line client source code](https://github.com/heroku/heroku) - which is in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build an HTTP client in Java, Jersey (Oracle's JAX-RS Reference implementation) is a good choice. It's client library is very similar to the client library that will be in standardized in JAX-RS 2.0.

With Jersey, you are also not limited to Java's build in HTTP connector but can plug in the (much better) Apache HTTP client connector. (All described in the Jersey docs)

http://jersey.java.net/